# Workbox: How to generate revision number for my CSS?

Tags: css, workbox, stenciljs

I am using workbox with stencilJS, configured as docs said: https://stenciljs.com/docs/service-workers

**The problem:**
When i change something in my CSS file - my app is not updated via new style until I manually unregister service worker.

**What I found**
There is no revision number in generated sw.js for my CSS file (so the browser will not know if this CSS file changed)

CSS file name: bootstrap-sandstone.css

Is there any way to tell workbox to generate revision number for given file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed name from bootstrap-sandstone.css to bootstrap_sandstone.css and revision number is being generated.

Didn’t investigated what exactly caused that.